# How can a nested loop with mutations on a HashMap be achieved in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrow-checker

I have the following (trimmed down) Rust code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Node {
    weight:   f64,
    outbound: f64,
}

struct Graph {
    edges: HashMap<u32, HashMap<u32, f64>>,
    nodes: HashMap<u32, Node>,
}

impl Graph {
    fn mutate(&mut self) {
        for (key, value) in self.nodes.iter() {
            if self.edges.contains_key(key) {
                for (target, weight) in self.edges[key].iter() {
                    self.nodes.entry(*target).or_insert(Node::new()).weight;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the code to compile due to Rust ownership rules ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4ef99860a4b9c195a057&version=stable)):

```
graph.rs:88:25: 88:35 error: cannot borrow `self.nodes` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
graph.rs:88                         self.nodes.entry(*target).or_insert(Node::new()).weight;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
```

If I change the first loop to use `HashMap::iter_mut()` instead, I get a different error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=754af4806b7ffc10fa2f&version=stable)):

```
graph.rs:88:25: 88:35 error: cannot borrow `self.nodes` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
graph.rs:88                         self.nodes.entry(*target).or_insert(Node::new()).weight;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
```

How can this kind of nested loop with mutations be achieved in Rust?

Comment: Hint: What would happen to your `nodes` iterator if inserting into `node` via `entry` had to reallocate the storage? Additionally, should the newly-inserted node be included in the iterator or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't insert or delete elements in a data structure while you are iterating over it.

As far as I know Rust iterators don't support modification either (like Java iterators' `remove()`).

So you are left with these options:

- If there are only a few modifications, you can collect them and execute them after the iteration is finished.
- If most of the data structure is modified, or if it is small enough that the overhead of copying doesn't matter, you can create a new, modified data structure that replaces the original one after the iteration. This is usually the idiomatic solution, using higher-order functions on iterators like `map`, `flat_map` or `filter`.

Comment: Is this still true? Sounds like a major limitation for a high-performance language such as Rust...