# When is it necessary to circumvent Rust's borrow checker?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing Conway's game of life to teach myself Rust. The idea is to implement a single-threaded version first, optimize it as much as possible, then do the same for a multi-threaded version.

I wanted to implement an alternative data layout which I thought might be more cache-friendly. The idea is to store the status of two cells for each point on a board next to each other in memory in a vector, one cell for reading the current generation's status from and one for writing the next generation's status to, alternating the access pattern for each
generation's computation (which can be determined at compile time).

The basic data structures are as follows:

```
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum CellStatus {
    DEAD,
    ALIVE,
}

/** 2 bytes */
pub struct CellRW(CellStatus, CellStatus);

pub struct TupleBoard {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    cells: Vec<CellRW>,
}

/** used to keep track of current pos with iterator e.g. */
pub struct BoardPos {
    x_pos: usize,
    y_pos: usize,
    offset: usize,
}

pub struct BoardEvo {
    board: TupleBoard,
}
```

The function that is causing me troubles:

```
impl BoardEvo {
    fn evolve_step<T: RWSelector>(&mut self) {
        for (pos, cell) in self.board.iter_mut() {
            //pos: BoardPos, cell: &mut CellRW
            let read: &CellStatus = T::read(cell); //chooses the right tuple half for the current evolution step
            let write: &mut CellStatus = T::write(cell);

            let alive_count = pos.neighbours::<T>(&self.board).iter() //<- can't borrow self.board again!
                    .filter(|&&status| status == CellStatus::ALIVE)
                    .count();

            *write = CellStatus::evolve(*read, alive_count);
        }
    }
}

impl BoardPos {
    /* ... */
    pub fn neighbours<T: RWSelector>(&self, board: &BoardTuple) -> [CellStatus; 8] {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The trait `RWSelector` has static functions for reading from and writing to a cell tuple (`CellRW`). It is implemented for two zero-sized types `L` and `R` and is mainly a way to avoid having to write different methods for the different access patterns.

The `iter_mut()` method returns a `BoardIter` struct which is a wrapper around a mutable slice iterator for the cells vector and thus has `&mut CellRW` as `Item` type. It is also aware of the current `BoardPos` (x and y coordinates, offset).

I thought I'd iterate over all cell tuples, keep track of the coordinates, count the number of alive neighbours (I need to know coordinates/offsets for this) for each (read) cell, compute the cell status for the next generation and write to the respective another half of the tuple.

Of course, in the end, the compiler showed me the fatal flaw in my design, as I borrow `self.board` mutably in the `iter_mut()` method and then try to borrow it again immutably to get all the neighbours of the read cell.

I have not been able to come up with a good solution for this problem so far. I did manage to get it working by making all
references immutable and then using an `UnsafeCell` to turn the immutable reference to the write cell into a mutable one.
I then write to the nominally immutable reference to the writing part of the tuple through the `UnsafeCell`.
However, that doesn't strike me as a sound design and I suspect I might run into issues with this when attempting to parallelize things.

Is there a way to implement the data layout I proposed in safe/idiomatic Rust or is this actually a case where you actually have to use tricks to circumvent Rust's aliasing/borrow restrictions?

Also, as a broader question, is there a recognizable pattern for problems which require you to circumvent Rust's borrow restrictions?

Comment: *using an `UnsafeCell`* — why did you go all the way to `UnsafeCell` as opposed to e.g. just a `Cell`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> When is it necessary to circumvent Rust's borrow checker?

It is needed when:

- the borrow checker is not advanced enough to see that your usage is safe
- you do not wish to (or cannot) write the code in a different pattern

As a concrete case, the compiler cannot tell that this is safe:

```
let mut array = [1, 2];
let a = &mut array[0];
let b = &mut array[1];
```

The compiler doesn't know what the implementation of `IndexMut` for a slice does at this point of compilation (this is a deliberate design choice). For all it knows, arrays always return the exact same reference, regardless of the index argument. *We* can tell that this code is safe, but the compiler disallows it.

You can rewrite this in a way that is obviously safe to the compiler:

```
let mut array = [1, 2];
let (a, b) = array.split_at_mut(1);
let a = &mut a[0];
let b = &mut b[0];
```

How is this done? [`split_at_mut` performs a runtime check](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.26.0/src/libcore/slice/mod.rs#L452-L462) to ensure that it actually *is* safe:

```
fn split_at_mut(&mut self, mid: usize) -> (&mut [T], &mut [T]) {
    let len = self.len();
    let ptr = self.as_mut_ptr();

    unsafe {
        assert!(mid <= len);

        (from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, mid),
         from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.offset(mid as isize), len - mid))
    }
}
```

For an example where the borrow checker is not *yet* as advanced as it can be, see [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423).

> I borrow `self.board` mutably in the `iter_mut()` method and then try to borrow it again immutably to get all the neighbours of the read cell.

If you know that the references don't overlap, then you can choose to use unsafe code to express it. However, this means *you* are also choosing to take on the responsibility of upholding all of Rust's invariants and avoiding [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

The good news is that this heavy burden is what every C and C++ programmer has to (or at least *should*) have on their shoulders for **every single line of code they write**. At least in Rust, you can let the compiler deal with 99% of the cases.

In many cases, there's tools like [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to allow for interior mutation. In other cases, you can rewrite your algorithm to take advantage of a value being a `Copy` type. In other cases you can use an index into a slice for a shorter period. In other cases you can have a multi-phase algorithm.

If you do need to resort to `unsafe` code, then try your best to hide it in a small area and expose safe interfaces.

Above all, many common problems have been asked about (many times) before:

- [How to iterate over mutable elements inside another mutable iteration over the same elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46003212/155423)
- [Mutating an item inside of nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29859892/155423)
- [How can a nested loop with mutations on a HashMap be achieved in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36281585/155423)
- [What's the Rust way to modify a structure within nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29414171/155423)
- [Nesting an iterator's loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38779588/155423)

Comment: Thank you for the very in depth explanation. It's funny I hadn't thought about using a simple indexed loop. I can't test right now but that should be one way to solve my problem. Also I had only skimmed the chapter about cells so I didn't have it on my radar. The compiler have me the idea about UnsafeCell when I tried to std::mem::transmute my immutable reference.

Comment: Having implement two different versions, one with an indexed loop and one with std::cell::Cell using interior mutability, it seems from some preliminary benchmarks, that using the indexed loop is significantly faster and using interior mutability is significantly slower when compared to my previous implementation, where I used an Unsafe cell to alter the value, not quite sure why that is but it's pretty interesting.

Comment: @Oliver that's actually very counter-intuitive to me. `Cell` doesn't have *any* runtime cost, while indexing an array should have a (tiny) out-of-bounds check. You did run your benchmarking with `--release` or `cargo bench`, correct?

Comment: Yes I did. I also did the best I could that the different implementations differ as little as possible, so implementation a) uses two indexed loops (x,y) and unchecked_get_mut() to access each cell and implementation b) uses cells and an coordinate aware iterator. When I use two indexed loops with regular get_mut() access  the results are much more close together but the loops still win. I don't know why that is but I had assumed that one version might allow for more compiler optimizations.