# Cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time when returning a Result containing a reference

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Why is the following invalid and what should I do instead to make it work?

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn mutable1(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn mutable2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
        self.mutable1()?;
        self.mutable1()?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

This code yields:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
8  |     fn mutable2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
9  |         self.mutable1()?;
   |         ----           - returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
   |         |
   |         first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |         self.mutable1()?;
   |         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

There are many questions already with the same error but I cannot use them to address this one as it's the presence of the implicit return provided by `?` that causes the problem, without `?` the code compiles successfully, yet with warnings.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1152735b67a3309315ef9f39e60fd349)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same problem discussed in [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423). Through *lifetime elision*, the lifetime of the `&str` is tied to the lifetime of `&self`. The compiler isn't aware that the borrow won't be used in the condition that an `Ok` is returned. It's overly conservative and disallows this code. This is a limitation of the current borrow checker implementation.

If you did need the lifetime of the `Err` variant to be tied to the lifetime of the `Foo` instance, there's not much to be done in safe Rust (unsafe Rust is [another story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50440074/155423)). In your case, however, it seems unlikely that your `&str` is intended to be tied to the lifetime of `self`, so you can use explicit lifetimes to avoid the problem. For example, a `&'static str` is a common basic error type:

```
impl Foo {
    fn mutable1(&mut self) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn mutable2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
        self.mutable1()?;
        self.mutable1()?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

> as it's the presence of the implicit return provided by `?`

Not really, as the same code with *explicit* returns has the same problem:

```
fn mutable2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
    if let Err(e) = self.mutable1() {
        return Err(e);
    }
    if let Err(e) = self.mutable1() {
        return Err(e);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:12:25
   |
8  |     fn mutable2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
9  |         if let Err(e) = self.mutable1() {
   |                         ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |             return Err(e);
   |                    ------ returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
11 |         }
12 |         if let Err(e) = self.mutable1() {
   |                         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: You mentioned:

> If you did need the lifetime of the Err variant to be tied to the lifetime of the Foo instance, there's not much to be done in safe Rust

I ran into a similar problem today:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78bc6983ab489fd772e87bea4c354055

I do need the lifetime of err to be connected to my 'machine' instance. I am curious how this can be achieved in Rust.

Comment: @skgbanga You'd need unsafe, as discussed in the linked question. I've now also linked another.

Answer (score 0):

Current limitation of the Rust borrow checker, we have to rewrite the corresponding methods to `static method`, for example

```rust
fn mutable2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &str> {
    ...
    if let Err(e) = Self::mutable1(&a, &b, &c) {
        return Err(e);
    }
    if let Err(e) = Self::mutable1(&e, &f, &g) {
        return Err(e);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```